# How to play an audio file sample

Tags: ios, swift3, avaudioplayer

Okay I'm trying to do something similar to iTunes not sure if it's still the same. It's when you click a song and it gives a sample of the audio file. This is my code looks.

[image]

The music file is like 2-3min long. I got the start time to start at 42sec seconds. However, the song finishes to the end. I'm trying to make the audio file a sample of 30sec. So it should start at 42sec and end at 1min and 12sec.

Would appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest using a `Timer`. You have to invalidate it if user stops playback prematurely.

Comment: Hey nshuman, AVFoundation is new to me. So if you don't mind providing me with some sample code I would appreciate it. In the meantime I'll keep reading more about AVFondation.

Comment: Hey @luis-ramirez, I have posted an answer with sample code, please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your audio sample starts playing, you can create a `Timer` object which will make your player stop in a given amount of time.

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var timer: Timer?

func prepareMusic() {
    ....

    // Your code to start playing sample

    audioPlayer.currentTime = 42
    audioPlayer.play()

    // Here we are stopping previous timer if there was any, and creating new one for 30 seconds. It will make player stop.

    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer(fire: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 30), interval: 0, repeats: false) { (timer) in 
        if self.audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            self.audioPlayer.stop()
        }
    }

    RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
}

func musicButton(sender: UIButton) {
    ....

    // If sample is stopped by user — stop timer as well

    if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

There is one more edge case I can think of — if you hide/close view controller, you might also want to stop that timer.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    timer?.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Thank you nshuman, it works perfectly. I need to read more about AVFoundation cause don't and Timer. Cause I don't fully know what is going on. Thank you again. :)